# wp7 cannot get current page from background worker

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, backgroundworker

Unfortunately, in windows phone 7 there's no "Broadcast Receiver" concept as in android, so I'm trying to do something like it.

In my application, I run a background worker that calls a function and upon finishing I have to make a refresh some data in a page. I don't know if the required page will be the current page at finish time so I have to make a test. I found this code in some forum:

```
var frame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
var startPage = frame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
```

this gives me a '`System.UnauthorizedAccessException`' exception on runtime. In fact, accessing all Application.Current properties gives the same exception. What I'm trying to understand, is that if I can't access the current page from a background worker or thread why would I need it anyway ? If I'm in main UI thread I know in what page I stand right ? Am I missing something here?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can only access `Application.Current` from the UI thread. Use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` from your background thread to delegate the execution to the UI thread:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
{
    // Your code needing Application.Current
});
```

Comment: I did that, but the code inside the begin invoke was not executed. the breakpoint moved from the curly brace to the curly brace and I dont know why

Comment: @NadaNaoushi Since you're delegating the execution to another thread, it's not supposed to execute immediately. To make it easier to debug, you can put the part in the `BeginInvoke` in a separate function:  `private void DoSomething() { your code... }`, then `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DoSomething);`